# JSON dumps into file with ensure_ascii=False

Tags: python-2.7

I want to write a JSON file with parameter ensure_ascii=False 
somehow it always gives me some error

"*--is not JSON serializable*"

Is there another way to write JSON file with ensure_ascii=False  ?

**I use Python 2.7

```js
ret = twitter_stream.statuses.filter(track='สวัสดี')

tweet_count = 3    for tweet in ret:
    tweet_count -= 1
    # We convert it back to the JSON format to print/score
    print ('----',tweet_count,'----')
    #print json.dumps(tweet,ensure_ascii=False,indent=4)
    if tweet_count <= 0:
        break

with io.open('data1.json', 'w',  encoding='utf-8') as outfile:
    outfile.write(json.dumps(ret, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4))
print("Done")
```

Comment: do a `type(tweet)` before json.dumps and post what is the output

Comment: the output is <class 'twitter.api.TwitterDictResponse'>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ret` is an iterator class object, and class objects are not json serializable hence cant be used with `json.dumps`

You need to do:

```
for tweet in ret:
    with io.open('data1.json', 'a',  encoding='utf-8') as outfile:
        outfile.write(json.dumps(tweet, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4))
```